# mathematical symbols for specific math equation

Tags: terminology, arithmetic, linear-programming

I am a master's student in the School of Software Engineering
and I have a question in math and in particular to give a label symbols.

For example,

the size of the basic block writes like this SBB
the size of the whole program , SWB.

I have introduced some mathematical relation in my thesis and would ask you if these labels are correct or not.

**SULi** : the size of unrolled loop i , where i in [1,n]

**SOLi** : the size of original loop i

**Nli**  : Number of times unrolling loop i

(i.e. assume that we have a loop and n=10, then we unroll loop 10 times)

**NPET** : New Program Execution Time

**OPET** : Old Program Execution Time

**NPZ**  : New Program Size

**OPZ**  : Old Program Size

Note( I am so sorry if this question is not appropriate for this forum, But I have mentioned that I am not a math student)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You assume society maintains some global standard of what constitutes acceptable notation.  It does not.  It is not unusual for a mathematician to introduce his/her own notation for describing something; then what matters is whether this helps the reader better understand what is being talked about, and whether this helps the author derive proofs.  Sometimes the notation takes on a larger life beyond the one paper; usually not.

The notation you introduce doesn't look bad to me, but of course I haven't seen how you use it in your thesis.  I recommend you review your notation with your advisor, who should be able to tell you if it helps or hurts comprehension of your thesis.